# How is the following related to the Gamma function?

Tags: definite-integrals

There's a shortcut formula in my book:

$$
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{m}\left(x\right)\cos^{n}\left(x\right)\,{\rm d}x
=
{\left[\left(m - 1\right)\left(m - 3\right)\ldots\,2\ \mbox{or}\ 1\right]
 \left[\left(n - 1\right)\left(n - 3\right)\ldots\,2\ \mbox{or}\ 1\right]
 \over
 \left(m + n\right)\left(m + n - 2\right)\ldots\,2\ \mbox{or}\ 1}
$$

On the topic it just says Gamma Function. Please answer using as simple terms as possible. I have aware only about elementary integration.

Comment: The relation is via the Beta function : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function

Comment: See also [Wallis' integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis'_integrals) and [double factorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial).

Answer (score 1):

Gamma function at integer argument is the factorial function, and the right hand side of your formula is a ratio of products of factorials...

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I said it should be in as simple terms as possible.

Comment: Does the RHS have double factorials?

Comment: @Shubham The RHS can be written as $(m-1)! (n-1)!/(m+n)!,$ and each factorial is a $\Gamma$ function...

Comment: But isn't (m-1)!=(m-1)(m-2)...3.2.1 ?

Answer (score 1):

What you have here is basically the beta function $\mathbf{B(m,n)}$. Now, $\mathbf{B(m,n)} = \frac{\Gamma(m).\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(m+n)}$. Also, for integer n, we have $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$. The result follows thereby.